# trigger.io and jquery mobile - slow on android?

Tags: jquery-mobile, trigger.io

I have a very basic test app using HTML5 + jQuery mobile (nothing happening over the network, etc.) and am using `TriggerIO`.  It is noticeably slower than any other app running on my Droid4, even after turning transitions off.

Is there something obvious in this seemingly simple formula I could be missing that would be causing the slowness?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery Mobile + Backbone.js template that is ready to go with trigger.io -

https://github.com/dragthor/jquery-mobile-backbone-template

Page transitions are enabled.  There is no harm giving it a try on your device.  Let me know if I can help.